# Giving or changing the implementation of method at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Recently i caught with the a thought of changing the implementation of method after deployment

When i googled about objective c runtime and all, came to know about method swizzling methodExchangeImplementations etc.

I know that it could be possible by https://rollout.io/
But my thought is how to do Hot Patching by myself for simple things.

my idea is injecting the code using webservice call.
Webservice should give a replacement for particular method.
That string has to be converted to executable code

What i want to know is ...
How to inject the code in existing method of enterprise application.

For ex:
Consider this method in objective c

```
-(void)fetchTheResult{
     // some code lines
}
```

After deployment i would like to change the method implementation to

```
-(void)fetchTheresult{

     NSLog(@"test log");
     //some Code lines
     //some more lines

}
```

Please guide me the way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question and you've some research to do to figure out an answer. Here as some things you can look into:

- First you've referenced Rollout, you could follow the same idea and send your update as JavaScript. You'll need to study how to call JavaScript, swizzle methods, and probably dynamically add methods - more on that in a moment.

  - An alternative you can investigate is dynamic library loading - you can open, and call code in, a library which your app loads at runtime. So you could look at sending your update as a library. You'll still need to do method swizzling and probably dynamically add methods...
  - As well as method swizzling you may find you need to dynamically add methods - e.g. so you have something to swap the existing implementation to. A good place to find out how to do that is Mike Ash's writings on KVO - go DuckDuckGo (or Google)

HTH

Answer (score -1):

It is not as easy as you think, at least in Objective C and other similar compiled languages. This kind of runtime changes to the code is only possible in interpreted languages like Javascript.

The basic problem is, the apps are not allowed to change the executable files themselves. The apps on iOS and Android run in a sandboxed environment, and thus have access to limited disk locations only.

Also, after compiling the code, the code does not know where the part of code is converted and stored in machine language. You have to understand the basics of compilers to understand this. There are heavy optimisations happening to your code during this process.

Comment: Yes of course @codetiger ! When this idea is stuck in mind, i go back to the basics of compilation,linking and runtime executions. Then only i conformed that it is possible in objective c. After all rollout is doing the good job on it. I just wonder how do we do by our own.